# Granting access to a restricted git shell

Tags: shell, ssh, centos, git

I tried setting up `git-shell` on our CentOS (6.4) system (after getting this working correctly on Ubuntu 13.10, maybe cross platform hot mess?)

my `/etc/passwd` shows

```
git:x:500:500:Web Archive VCS:/home/git:/usr/bin/git-shell
```

and my shell commands are in `/home/git/git-shell-commands`

```
[root@domain git]# cd /home/git/git-shell-commands/ && tree
.
├── addkey
├── create
├── drop
├── help
└── list
```

But ssh'ing in is still giving me

```
Last login: Fri Nov 15 12:14:49 2013 from localhost
fatal: What do you think I am? A shell?
Connection to localhost closed.
```

I am working off of this resource

[Hosting an admin-friendly git server with git-shell](http://planzero.org/blog/2012/10/24/hosting_an_admin-friendly_git_server_with_git-shell)

There was some confusion that this was licensed GIT commands (push/pull etc) but this is a restricted shell with pre set commands! Please anyone reading this make note ;)

Installer script if you want to see steps

https://github.com/ehime/bash-tools/blob/master/git-server-setup.sh

I still have not been able to resolve this over the weekend, I HAVE added

```
# add to shells
echo '/usr/bin/git-shell' >> /etc/shells

# Prevent full login for security reasons
chsh -s /usr/bin/git-shell git
```

And have double checked that GIT Shell actually exists in `/usr/bin`

```
[root@domain bin]# ll /usr/bin | grep git
-rwxr-xr-x. 105 root root    1138056 Mar  4  2013 git
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root    1138056 Mar  4  2013 git-receive-pack
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root     457272 Mar  4  2013 git-shell
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root    1138056 Mar  4  2013 git-upload-archive
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root     467536 Mar  4  2013 git-upload-pack
```

This IS a root account that I am dealing with though, could that have
something to do with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, this feature has been introduced in git 1.7.4. 
`git --version` gave me 1.7.1 on a base CentOS 6.4 install so
that was the beginning of the issue =/

If you experience this problem, check your git version. Here's 
is an updater script that I wrote to aid you in your troubles.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Git updater for RHEL systems

# CPR : Jd Daniel :: Ehime-ken
# MOD : 2013-11-18 @ 09:28:49

# REF : http://goo.gl/ditKWu
# VER : Version 1.1

# ROOT check
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "This script must be run as su" 1>&2 ; exit 1
fi

yum install -y perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker gettext-devel expat-devel curl-devel zlib-devel openssl-devel
cd /usr/local/src

git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git && cd git
make && make prefix=/usr install

git --version
exit 0
```

Thanks to everyone who took the time to look into this, I appreciate it greatly.